# Zend for picture uploads needing to resize images

Tags: zend-framework, upload, resize, image

So, I am using Zend to handle my image uploads. This script works well, but I was wondering if there is a way to resize the image that is being uploaded no matter what the current size is. I've seen 2 similar posts, but their code was entirely different, thus would be difficult to translate into mine from theirs. If possible, I would really like to not have to use extensions, but I will if I have to. Any ideas?

```
if (isset($_POST['upload'])) {
require_once('scripter/lib.php');
//try {
$destination = 'C:\----';
$uploader = new Zend_File_Transfer_Adapter_Http();
$uploader->setDestination($destination);
$filename = $uploader->getFileName(NULL, FALSE);
$uploader->addValidator('Size', FALSE, '10000kB');
$uploader->addValidator('ImageSize', FALSE, array('minheight' => 100, 'minwidth' => 100));
//$pic = $filename;
if (!$uploader->isValid() || $errors) {
    $messages = $uploader->getMessages();
} else {
//$pic = $filename;
$no_spaces = str_replace(' ', '_', $filename, $renamed);
$uploader->addValidator('Extension', FALSE, 'gif, png, jpg');
$recognized = FALSE;
if ($uploader->isValid()) {
    $recognized = TRUE;
} else {
    $mime = $uploader->getMimeType();
    $acceptable = array('jpg' => 'image/jpeg',
                        'png' => 'image/png',
                        'gif' => 'image/gif');
    $key = array_search($mime, $acceptable);
    if (!$key) {
        $messages[] = 'Unrecognized image type';
    } else {
        $no_spaces = "$no_spaces.$key";
        $recognized = TRUE;
        $renamed = TRUE;
    }
}
$uploader->clearValidators();
if ($recognized) {
    $existing = scandir($destination);
    if (in_array($no_spaces, $existing)) {
        $dot = strrpos($no_spaces, '.');
        $base = substr($no_spaces, 0, $dot);
        $extension = substr($no_spaces, $dot);
        $i = 1;
        do {
            $no_spaces = $base . '_' . $i++ . $extension;
        } while (in_array($no_spaces, $existing));
        $renamed = TRUE;
    }
$uploader->addFilter('Rename', array('target' => $no_spaces));
$success = $uploader->receive();
if (!$success) {
$messages = $uploader->getMessages();
} else {
    //$pic = $no_spaces;
    $uploaded = "$filename uploaded successfully";
    $pic = $filename;
    if ($renamed) {
        $pic = "imgs/upld/" . $no_spaces;
        $uploaded .= " and renamed $no_spaces";
        //$pic = $no_spaces;
        //$pic = $uploader->getFileName(NULL, FALSE);

    } else {$pic = "imgs/upld/" . $filename;;}
    $messages[] = "$uploaded";
    //$pic = $no_spaces;

}
```

Comment: I also saw someone say on another post to use Zend/Filter/ImageSize.php, but there is no file named ImageSize.php, not even on the full latest release.

Comment: Guess I hit a brick wall, since the polycaster zend filter imagesize is seemingly broken.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Zend Framework does not ship with a component for handling images.

Good News! PHP has several components that are really good at dealing with all kinds of image issues.

GD (one of those great PHP extensions) is currently shipped as a core extension for PHP, perhaps you will find it useful.

Maybe this will help: http://phpcodeforbeginner.blogspot.com/2013/04/resize-image-or-crop-image-using-gd.html

(not really trying to be too snarky ;)

Comment: Thank you. :)
I've been searching all night for a decent way to do this. I'll definitely give your option a shot, although it seems it might be somewhat difficult to edit what I have to your example. Another interesting post I found, although I haven't tried it is  PHP Thumbnailer Class v2.0. But yes, thanks for your post RockyFord, I will definitely give your post suggestion a good read and take a step back before I jump any further into this!

Comment: Sometimes it'd difficult to remember that Zend Framework is just PHP and that all of the available PHP resources will work. Image resizing is a common problem and there are tons of solutions. http://www.phpclasses.org/ is often a good place to start.